# Grails row number criteria

Tags: grails, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Short question:

How do I get the row number as an extra column in grails criteria?

I could only find rowCount which is not what I need

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure. I want a row Number (which is basically the number in the leaderboard because I sort on a specific value). I do this because I want the rank of a specific User in the board

Comment: ask yourself: how would you do it in a good'ol SQL query?

Comment: I would do this: SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER(), FROM user

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate your result set with `eachWithIndex`.